# NameNotFound Exception when calling PackageManager.getPackageInfo

Tags: android

I am trying to organize my application into packages because it will have several comprehensive list menus. The way I am trying to populate the menus is by finding the activities in each package.

The problem may be with the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="machinists.toolkit"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:name=".MTEActivity" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ExceptionActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.ReferenceActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.CalculatorActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.reference.FormulasActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.reference.MaterialsActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

and the snippet in question is:

```
try {
        this.activities = this.packageManager.getPackageInfo(this.packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).activities;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {...
```

In this instance this.packageName solves to machinist.toolkit.activities.reference

The getPackageInfo method calls for the full name of the package and that should be correct if I am understanding.

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The getPackageInfo method calls for the full name of the package and that should be correct if I am understanding.

No. You are confusing the package of a class and the package of the application. The value supplied to `getPackageInfo()` is the package of the application (i.e., the value of your `package` attribute in the `<manifest>` element).

Comment: Okay. I figured it was something like that. Thanks.

Comment: So if I pull all the activities from the package into the ActivityInfo[] array should I just parse the array for the information I want or is there a better way to separate the views?

Comment: @daedalus0x1a4: Android has no real concept of sub-packages, so you will just have to iterate over the results and filter out the ones you want.